# SharedPreferences does not return the default value

Tags: java, android

I have a sharedpreferences and I have created a method for it to be checked if it is the user's first time in the app. But it always returns the opposite of the default value.

My code:

```
public static Boolean getFirstOnApp(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref =  context.getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return pref.getBoolean(KEY_FIRST_TIME_ON_APP, true);
}
```

Is always returns `false`.

I call it on my controller:

```
 if (SaveSharedPreferences.getFirstOnApp(context)) {
            fabAtivaMapeamento.performClick();
            SaveSharedPreferences.setFirstOnApp(context, false);
        }
```

`SaveSharedPreferences.setFirstOnApp(context, false);` has never been called before. It is only changed within this `If`

I already uninstalled the app, forced it to stop, cleared data and cache.

How to solve?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/alirezat775/kesho, kesho is a simple library for cache any object. I will hope helpful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this to check if it's first time or not

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (pref.getBoolean(KEY_FIRST_TIME_ON_APP, false)) {

           //in here it's not for first time

        } else {

             //in here it's first time
        }
```

Comment: But that's what I do, is not ?

Comment: change this line return `pref.getBoolean(KEY_FIRST_TIME_ON_APP, true);` into `pref.getBoolean(KEY_FIRST_TIME_ON_APP, false);` after that if works or not let me know

Comment: I changed, and the else statement was called.

Comment: if my answer helps you please accept it to help the others

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** - Check if the following works.

```
public static Boolean getFirstOnApp(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref =  context.getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //Check if the shared preference key exists.
    //This way, you can determine if the fault is here or elsewhere.
    if (pref.contains(KEY_FIRST_TIME_ON_APP)) {
        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_FIRST_TIME_ON_APP, true);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

Check if you've set your application to allow backup in the manifest `android:allowBackup="true"`.
Set it as false, uninstall and then reinstall the app.

```
android:allowBackup=“false”
```

In case that doesn't fix the issue, then try setting the following in your manifest, uninstalling the app and then reinstalling it.

```
android:fullBackupContent="false"
```

Comment: it keep false, always false.

Comment: I've updated my answer, do check it. Check if the preference contains the key. You should be able to use the debugger to determine if the `SharedPreference` persists even after app uninstall.

Comment: Then the issue lies elsewhere, the key **should not exist** after the app is uninstalled & reinstalled.

Comment: Even cleaning the data and uninstalling it, the key exists

Comment: Add the class with the `getFirstOnApp` & `setFirstOnApp` method and your manifest in the question.

Comment: I've created new file of preferences. And it work. I don't know why, but, work.